# String array not getting correct values in a function

Tags: c

I made an array of strings(matrix of chars), and I am trying to make a function that will read the strings and store them in an array. This is the function I made:

```
void input_strings(char **array, int n){
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       scanf("%s",&array[i]);
       printf("%s \n",&array[i]);
   }
}
```

I added the printf() to verify that the input was doing alright in the function, and indeed printf() does return what I inputed previously using scanf().

But when I try to access the array fields after the input function, I get random garbage on my screen. This is what my main function looks like:

```
int main() {

char string_array[n][stringsize];
input_strings(&string_array, n);
printf("%s",&string_array[1]);
return 0;
```

}

n and stringsize are global variables large enough. Why does the program print out ���� instead of the string I inputed?

Edit: Edited the matrix from char** string_array[n][stringsize] to charstring_array[n][stringsize], the problem still persists.

Edit 2: So the problem was that a char matrix was incompatible with the function parameters. I fixed the issue by declaring the string_array in the following way.

```
    char ** string_array = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        string_array[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*stringsize);
    }
```

Also when declared this way, the function call should look like this:

```
    input_strings(string_array, n);
```

Comment: `char** string_array[n][stringsize];` is a two dimensional array of `char**` - with uninitialized pointers

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I just changed that real quick, I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you a warning about `input_strings(&string_array, n);`, as `&string_array` is **not** a `char**`(and you should never ignore compiler warnings)

Comment: Try to call function from `main()`  like: `input_strings(string_array, n);` without `&` (pass it by value,  no by reference)

Comment: @JuMoGar Tried it, still the same outcome.

Comment: @UnholySheep I didn't notice any warnings, but then again I'm still not quite experienced with c. What do you suggest that I put in the function call?

Comment: `&array[i]` has type `char **`, however the argument for `%s` must have type `char *`

Comment: In `printf ` do the same,  remove `&`. It should work

Comment: You should not try to run a program that had errors (and if you don't see error messages, fix your compiler settings before doing anything else)

Comment: @M.M I just found the compiler warning. Thanks for that info. I'm still not sure how to correctly change the string_array with a function.

Comment: @kulijana there are examples in the first linked question (that question has `float` instead of `char` but the code is otherwise the same)

Comment: You will benefit from this Answer to your Question drafted only to find the question closed [Your Answer](https://pastebin.com/w9yh3yMg) -- good for one-week.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, the correct way to pass the address is simply string_array. So, `input_strings(string_array, n);` or even `input_strings(&(string_array[0][0]), n);` which is the address of the first column of the first row.

Comment: No, both of these are wrong

Comment: Didn't work, the issue persists.